# Is there a way to hide bars in a plotly express bar chart by default?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, plotly-express

So I am working on a data visualisation project using plotly express. My current plot uses one dataframe, and each of the 3 columns of said dataframe is a unique bar on one plot.

Is there a way to hide 2 of these bars by default and only have them activated by clicking on the legend?

This is what it looks like currently by default:
[Current](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jkIRF.png)

And here is what I would like it to look like by default:
[Desired](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xXurK.png)

Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

you can check this thread in https://community.plotly.com/t/set-traces-to-be-toggled-off-by-default/34054

You can hide with (example)

```
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(y=[3, 4, 5], visible='legendonly'))
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this when you aren't adding each trace separately, I'm adding the data to the plot using `df.columns` rather than `y=[df1,df2,df3]`